# SBCL bypass debugger and print error for display in other environment?

Tags: error-handling, runtime-error, common-lisp, sbcl

I am controlling SBCL through shell commands with the environment MaxMSP.

Typically my commands are :
sbcl --core some/path/to/a/.core/file --script my/script/generated/in/max

Everything works wonderfully except when errors happen...
In that case I don't get any result but also no way to know what went wrong except evaluating the same command in the Terminal, where the SBCL debugger shows up.

Is there a way to just disable the debugger for this evaluation — typically give up if you meet an error — but then to "echo" the actual content of the error?

Typically to get the actual string that says something like
"The value
    'TOTO
  is not of type
    NUMBER
  when binding SB-KERNEL::X", so I can see it directly from Max with going to the terminal?

Thanks for your help !
Best,

Julien

I tried adding --non-interactive on top of my command, it helps but it's definitely not what I need.

Seems I should work with *debug-io* somehow but I'm not sure how to access its content :(

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use [`--disable-debugger`](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Command-Line-Options):

```
$ echo '(error "Oh no")' > script.lisp 
$ sbcl --disable-debugger --load $PWD/script.lisp 
This is SBCL 1.5.2.33-d415e2949, an implementation of ANSI Common Lisp.
More information about SBCL is available at <http://www.sbcl.org/>.

SBCL is free software, provided as is, with absolutely no warranty.
It is mostly in the public domain; some portions are provided under
BSD-style licenses.  See the CREDITS and COPYING files in the
distribution for more information.
While evaluating the form starting at line 1, column 0
  of #P"/tmp/script.lisp":
Unhandled SIMPLE-ERROR in thread #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "main thread" RUNNING
                                    {10005C85B3}>:
  Oh no

Backtrace for: #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {10005C85B3}>
0: (SB-DEBUG::DEBUGGER-DISABLED-HOOK #<SIMPLE-ERROR "Oh no" {1003643C33}> #<unused argument> :QUIT T)
1: (SB-DEBUG::RUN-HOOK *INVOKE-DEBUGGER-HOOK* #<SIMPLE-ERROR "Oh no" {1003643C33}>)
2: (INVOKE-DEBUGGER #<SIMPLE-ERROR "Oh no" {1003643C33}>)
3: (ERROR "Oh no")
4: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (ERROR "Oh no") #<NULL-LEXENV>)
5: (EVAL-TLF (ERROR "Oh no") 0 NIL)
6: ((LABELS SB-FASL::EVAL-FORM :IN SB-INT:LOAD-AS-SOURCE) (ERROR "Oh no") 0)
7: ((LAMBDA (SB-KERNEL:FORM &KEY :CURRENT-INDEX &ALLOW-OTHER-KEYS) :IN SB-INT:LOAD-AS-SOURCE) (ERROR "Oh no") :CURRENT-INDEX 0)
8: (SB-C::%DO-FORMS-FROM-INFO #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (SB-KERNEL:FORM &KEY :CURRENT-INDEX &ALLOW-OTHER-KEYS) :IN SB-INT:LOAD-AS-SOURCE) {10036436CB}> #<SB-C::SOURCE-INFO {1003643683}> SB-C::INPUT-ERROR-IN-LOAD)
9: (SB-INT:LOAD-AS-SOURCE #<SB-INT:FORM-TRACKING-STREAM for "file /tmp/script.lisp" {1003641C13}> :VERBOSE NIL :PRINT NIL :CONTEXT "loading")
10: ((FLET SB-FASL::THUNK :IN LOAD))
11: (SB-FASL::CALL-WITH-LOAD-BINDINGS #<CLOSURE (FLET SB-FASL::THUNK :IN LOAD) {7F13FE6777EB}> #<SB-INT:FORM-TRACKING-STREAM for "file /tmp/script.lisp" {1003641C13}>)
12: ((FLET SB-FASL::LOAD-STREAM :IN LOAD) #<SB-INT:FORM-TRACKING-STREAM for "file /tmp/script.lisp" {1003641C13}> NIL)
13: (LOAD #P"/tmp/script.lisp" :VERBOSE NIL :PRINT NIL :IF-DOES-NOT-EXIST T :EXTERNAL-FORMAT :DEFAULT)
14: (SB-IMPL::PROCESS-EVAL/LOAD-OPTIONS ((:LOAD . "/tmp/script.lisp")))
15: (SB-IMPL::TOPLEVEL-INIT)
16: ((FLET SB-UNIX::BODY :IN SAVE-LISP-AND-DIE))
17: ((FLET "WITHOUT-INTERRUPTS-BODY-14" :IN SAVE-LISP-AND-DIE))
18: ((LABELS SB-IMPL::RESTART-LISP :IN SAVE-LISP-AND-DIE))
```

Note that the trace is printed and then program exits.

Alternatively, you could set [`*DEBUGGER-HOOK*`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_debugg.htm) to a custom function that is called when entering the debugger, in which you print the error and call `(sb-ext:quit)`, for example.

For example:

```
(setf *debugger-hook*
      (lambda (condition old-hook)
        (declare (ignore old-hook))
        (format *error-output*
                 "Caught error: ~a"
                 condition)
        (finish-output *error-output*)
        (sb-ext:quit)))
```

The code is almost the same if you prefer to use [`HANDLER-CASE`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_hand_1.htm) inside your *script*:

```
(handler-case (...main...)
  (condition (c) ...log and quit..))
```

Comment: That's the problem, I don't want to define my own error message, I would like to retrieve the one produced by the Lisp itself, do you know a way to do that?

Comment: If there is public doc about MaxMSP I would be happy to read it. But if you write directly something to query-io, what happens? if a simple print does send the text to a GUI widhget, then you only need to wrap your code with a handler-case that catch any error and print it in that stream. Do you have more information about how MaxMSP works? it looks interesting.

Comment: Yes it's all documented but maybe not worth diving into for you, it's proprietary software (visual programming) dedicated mostly to musicians. There is a "shell" third-party object that can be used to interact with the mac's terminal somehow — I suppose it's some kind of emulation. But I don't use the actual result from it : I use it evaluate scripts where SBCL is called and writes by itself its own results to temp files (with-open-file etc.).
But it seems whenever an error happens the SBCL debugger just interrupts everything and doesn't really "print" it. *query-io* doesn't help either

Comment: Assuming the shell is https://github.com/jeremybernstein/shell, it looks like you can only communicate results with stdout and stderr streams, which corresponds to *standard-output* and *error-output* in Lisp. You probably need to catch all errors (see http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/beyond-exception-handling-conditions-and-restarts.html) and log them to *error-output*, then quit.

Comment: Wow thanks, you nailed it ! Actually I wasn't sure (at my level) of how to catch those errors after Seibel's chapter you suggested. But you really put me on the right way : there was a small helpfile I missed in Bernstein's object that explained how to append error-output to standard-output in the printed result in Max. It's not extremely clean but I managed to filter everything I didn't need from the debugger, and isolated the error string I needed. Thank you so much again ! Best, Julien